# css.erb file in Sinatra

Tags: css, ruby, amazon-s3, sinatra, assets

Is it possible to have a css.erb file in Sinatra for serving images from AWS for example. I am pulling my static assets from AWS and can pull in an image in my view for example

```
<%= image_tag( aws_asset "/assets/img/banner2.jpg") %>
```

aws_asset is a helper that sets AWS url

```
helpers do
 def aws_asset( path )
 File.join settings.asset_host, path
 end
end

configure :development do 
 set :asset_host, "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}" 
end
```

so the question is how do i get a background image from  my css file to pull that image from AWS

EDIT

Current setup

myapp.rb

```
get "/assets/css/style.css" do
erb :style 
end
```

layout.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "/assets/css/style.css"  %>
```

style.css

```
body {
background: url('<%= aws_asset "/assets/img/banner1.jpg" %>');

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Forget my other comment, I see you've asked the question already! :)

Comment: Check the actual output (in browser's source view or developer console) and check that the URL's being produced are correct. You can just visit them and you should see the image.

Comment: well they dont appear as a link as I would normally expect, you cant click on it to view the file,  example, background: url('<%= aws_asset "/assets/img/banner1.jpg" %>');

Comment: Either rename `style.css` to `style.erb` (nothing else needs to be done, just restart), or to `style.css.erb` _and_ also replace `erb :style` with `erb :"style.css"`.

Comment: ok, so adding the .erb ext to the css file stops all the css being rendered, so does just a .erb ext. second suggestion made no difference either?

Comment: You can either have an [ERB template](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Erb%20Templates) (that sits in the `views` directory) served by a route, or you can put a CSS file _with no ERB in it_ into the public directory and have that served as a static file. You can't have an ERB file with a .css extension rendered via ERB (also with helpers from the Sinatra app) and served from the public directory.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using ERB already for this:

```
body
{
  background-image:url('banner2.jpg');
}
```

would become:

```
body
{
  background-image:url('<%= aws_asset "/assets/img/banner2.jpg" %>');
}
```

That's the simple answer. However, since you're possibly serving quite a few files from AWS then using a helper in all the different places you need it might get tiresome, and also difficult - maybe you'll want to precompile the CSS in future etc. This is when it would be a good idea to hide some of the implementation using Rack middleware.

```
module MySinatraApp

  # A remote file called banner2.jpg would have the relative path
  # in the app of "/images/extra/banner2.jpg"
  # and on being requested, this middleware/app would check if
  # the remote file is in the list you've given
  # if it is, a 307 redirect is issued.
  # If it isn't, then a 404. Use with Rack::Cascade to pass on
  # to another app that may serve a local version of the file.
  # @example
  #   use RemoteImageServer, 
  #       :asset_host => "//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
  #       :files      => ["banner2.jpg", "blah.gif"]
  class RemoteImageServer
    DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
      subdir:        "images/extra",
      cascade:       false # until I work it out more, see note at bottom
    }

    def initialize(app,options={})
      app, options = app, DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge(options)
      @asset_host = options[:asset_host]
      files = options[:files]
      @subdir = options[:subdir]
      @http_path_files = files.map{|file| File.join @subdir, file }
    end

    def call( env )
      dup._call( env ) # for thread safety
    end

    def _call( env )
      request = Rack::Request.new env
      if request.path_info.start_with? @subdir
        response = Rack::Response.new env
        if @http_path_files.include? request.path_info
          response.redirect File.join(@asset_host,request.path_info), 307
          response.finish
        else
          if @options[:cascade]
            response.status = 404
            response.finish
          end
        end
      else
        @app.call env
      end
    end
  end

  class MainApp < Sinatra::Base do
    # other stuff here…
  end

end
```

You either use this [in the Sinatra Application](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Rack%20Middleware), or in the rackup file. I'd prefer the later for this <del>and use [Rack::Cascade](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Cascade.html):</del>

<del>run Rack::Cascade.new([
  MySinatraApp::RemoteImageServer,
  MySinatraApp::MainApp])</del> (I'm not sure how best to pass the options when using a cascade, I might have to think about this more).

```
  use RemoteImageServer, 
    :asset_host => "//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    :files      => ["banner2.jpg", "blah.gif"]
  run MySinatraApp::MainApp
```

That way the remote host is "hidden" behind a relative url, and you could replace the remote files with a local one, or change remote provider easily. The Sinatra app at the end would also still serve any local files from its public folder. This code, is though, completely untested! There may be a Rack middleware that already does this ([Rack Static Fallback](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-static_fallback) might be close).

---

Edit: serving CSS via ERB.

There are 2 main ways:

- Precompile the CSS and serve it via the `public_folder`.
- Serve it from a `get` route.

#### Precompiling the CSS

There's probably a gem or something to do this (maybe a [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) helper or something), but this would work in a console:

```
require 'erb'
require 'tilt'
template = Tilt.new( "path/to/erb/file" )
File.open "app/public/stylesheets/main.css", "w" do |f|
  f.write template.render
end
```

Since the compiled CSS file will reside in Sinatra's public directory, it will be served as a static file. Since you've got the `aws_asset` helper from Sinatra in the file you'd need to change it slightly, either redefine the helper in the console before running it, or hard code the path, or [pass it a variable instead](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt#basic-usage).

#### Serve it from a Sinatra get route

```
get "/css/main.css" do
  erb :main # it will server main.erb from the views directory
            # and it will have access to helpers.
end
```

Since it's a file that won't change often, you'll be best adding [cache control headers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Cache%20Control).

Comment: Wow, thanks Iain, great answer, gives me something new to look at, never done this before :)

Comment: also ive tried out background: url('<%= aws_asset "/assets/img/bg-pattern.png" %>')repeat #f2f2f2; but the image does not show? anything else i need to do, change extension of stylesheet?

Comment: @Richlewis is the rest of the CSS from that stylesheet working? You'll  need a route to serve it, or to precompile it into the public directory.

Comment: yes all the rest of the css works? would you mind explaining the rest please?

Comment: @Richlewis I've added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: thanks iain, so this is declared (get route) once and not for every view i take it, at the top of my app.rb, it will apply to all views?

Comment: @Richlewis It will serve "yourdomain.com/css/main.css" (according to the example above), so treat it as if it was just a CSS file and fill in the route in views and other places just as an normal URL to a CSS file. Put it in the layout file in a stylesheet link and it will get loaded wherever the layout is used.

Comment: when you say style sheet link, you mean <%= stylesheet_link_tag %> like in rails?

Comment: @Richlewis well, anything that produce a valid `<link>` tag (so, yes). Basically, treat the URL to the CSS like any URL to CSS, forget about how it's served. Then you'll use it correctly :)

Comment: sorry iain, so in my layout for example i could do this <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "/assets/css/style.css"  %> but that doesnt complete the job does it? do i then use the get in myapp.rb

Comment: @Richlewis yes, do the `get` too, just make sure the route matches the one you use, so `get "/assets/css/style.css" do`…

Comment: ok so i have updated my question with what i have done, doesn't seem to be pulling the background images in